# Pandas resample error: resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'offset'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to resample a dataframe, and I would like to offset the data. I'm getting the error:

`resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'offset'`

I have tried running the sample code from the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

```py
start, end = '2000-10-01 23:30:00', '2000-10-02 00:30:00'
rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='7min')
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(len(rng)) * 3, index=rng)

ts.resample('17min', offset='23h30min').sum()
```

This results in the same error. I have upgraded pandas to the current latest version ('1.0.3').

Update:

In the documentation, under offset it states "New in version 1.1.0."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to install pandas 1.1.0. The can be done by building pandas from source.

Clone the dev version of pandas from github:

`git clone https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases`

Install cython:

`pip install cython`

cd pandas, and then:

`python -m pip install -e . --no-build-isolation --no-use-pep517`

Answer (score 0):

You've made a small mistake. There is no `offset` parameter. It is `loffset`.

> See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) here (stable version documentation).

So it should be:

```
rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='7min')
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(len(rng)) * 3, index=rng)

ts.resample('17min', loffset='23h30min').sum()
```

Comment: loffset does the following according to the documentation: "Adjust the resampled time labels." I want to offset the whole dataframe, not just the time label. If you look at the documentation offset is the last parameter in the list.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find any offset parameter in the documentation.

Comment: I see you are correct, the link I provided is to the documentation of the stable version. The offset parameter is new in version 1.1.0, and listed in the documentation of the dev version: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this one may help:

`ts.shift(1)`